# Installed Docker and Try to create new files with permission deny message

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I installed docker on my computer and also installed Jupyter on it. However, when I try to create new program or folder on the browser, it generates a "permission deny" message.

[image]

I also try to start the terminal on this browser and create a folder using terminal, it generates the same permission deny message.

[image]

I couldn't figure out what happens to it.

Answer (score 2):

It's something to do with the permission docker uses and the permission that's granted by the OS.

After some fiddling I found that if `uid` and `gid` matches between the OS and the container, then there's no problem. Use `id` in shell to get your current ids, and then set following flags: `-e NB_UID=[uid] -e NB_GID=[gid]`

The full command might look something like:

`docker run -d -p 8888:8888 --user root -e GRANT_SUDO=yes -e NB_UID=1011 -e NB_GID=1011 -v $(pwd):/home/jovyan/work jupyter/scipy-notebook:latest`